# Is a class member free of cache line issue?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-6

In the `TThread` class there is a class member (property) named `Terminated`. 
There is also an `procedure Terminate;` which merely sets `Terminated` to `True`. 
When we inherit from `TThread` there are some cases where we check for terminated. The following pool/loop is just to demonstrate a possible situation:

```
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Work;
  end;
```

What is the garantee that terminated will never be cached by the processor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi compiler is not at all aggressive in its optimisations. It treats members of classes as being *global*. That means, essentially, not *local*. The compiler knows that other parties can see the variable. Unlike a simple local variable.

And for global variables, the compiler will not enregister its access of that variable. So whenever you read the variable the value is read from memory. Likewise when writing, the value is written to memory.

All that remains is the memory caching. The memory system ensures consistency between the different processor caches.

So, there is no problem with the `TThread` implementation of termination.

Comment: Amazing, Is there an oficial documentation about it? Now I see, is implicit in the property's documentation

Comment: No, there is no documentation at all on such details.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because of its completness

Answer (score 4):

Delphi *never* caches property values in registers, if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: I just accepted @David's answer because of its completness, okay?

Comment: That is absolutely fine :)